# parent child structure in R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a csv that contains an org structure as follows plus some additional columns. I use R to create charts and it works great !.
The challenge is when trying to create the charts for a subset manager and its children/grandchildren. 
Is there any filtering that is possible in dplr or any alternative package?

```
Sample format:
emp_id  mgr_id  nest_id
A        A      0
B        A      1
C        B      2
 D       C      3
  D1     D      4
  D2     D      4
 E       C      3
  E1     E      4
 F       C      3
G        B      2
 H       G      3
```

The subset I need is for manager "C"

**Scenario 1**:emp_id==C should contain all nodes of 'D','D1','D2','E','E1','F'

expected structure:

```
manager,all_children
C       D
C       D1
C       D2
C       E
C       E1
C       F
```

**Scenario 2**:emp_id==C should contain all above nodes but retain mgr_id structure for 'D','E'
expected structure:

```
manager,all_children
C        D
C        E
C        F
D        D1
D        D2
E        E1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using functions from `dplyr` and `data.table`. `dt3` is the output for scenario 1, while dt4 is the output for scenario 2.

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "emp_id  mgr_id  nest_id
A        A      0
                 B        A      1
                 C        B      2
                 D       C      3
                 D1     D      4
                 D2     D      4
                 E       C      3
                 E1     E      4
                 F       C      3
                 G        B      2
                 H       G      3",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  # Filter levels lower than 1
  filter(nest_id > 1) %>%
  mutate(group_id = ifelse(nest_id > 2, 0, 1)) %>%
  # Create "run_id", which will be used to fill manager label
  mutate(run_id = rleid(group_id)) %>%
  mutate(run_id = ifelse(run_id %% 2 == 0, run_id - 1, run_id)) %>%
  group_by(run_id) %>%
  mutate(manager = first(emp_id)) %>%
  # Select for manager C
  filter(manager %in% "C") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Remove rows if manager == emp_id
  filter(manager != emp_id) %>%
  rename(all_children = emp_id)

# Scenario 1
dt3 <- dt2 %>% select(manager, all_children)

# Scenario 2
dt4 <- dt2 %>%
  select(manager = mgr_id, all_children) %>%
  arrange(manager, all_children)
```

Comment: Thank you for both the responses and both are working great on the dummy data i provided plus a demo csv that i have. Let me execute this on the real data and provide updates asap.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the base package with `by` which creates a df list for every level of *mgr_id* (not just C):

SCENARIO 1

```
dfList <- by(df, df$mgr_id, function(i){
  names(i) <- paste0(names(i), "_")     # SUFFIX UNDERSCORE (TO AVOID DUP COLUMNS)

  child <- merge(i, df, by.x="mgr_id_", by.y="emp_id")[,1:2]
  grandchild <- merge(child, df, by.x="emp_id_", by.y="mgr_id")[c("mgr_id_", "emp_id")]

  names(child) <- gsub("*_$", "", names(child))              # REMOVE LAST UNDERSCORE
  names(grandchild) <- gsub("*_$", "", names(grandchild))    # REMOVE LAST UNDERSCORE

  rbind(child, grandchild)
})

dfList$C

#   mgr_id emp_id
# 1      C      D
# 2      C      E
# 3      C      F
# 4      C     D1
# 5      C     D2
# 6      C     E1
```

SCENARIO 2 *(where the selected columns change in grandchild and then first column rename)*

```
dfList <- by(df, df$mgr_id, function(i){
  names(i) <- paste0(names(i), "_")     # SUFFIX UNDERSCORE (TO AVOID DUP COLUMNS)

  child <- merge(i, df, by.x="mgr_id_", by.y="emp_id")[,1:2]
  grandchild <- merge(child, df, by.x="emp_id_", by.y="mgr_id")[c("emp_id_", "emp_id")]

  names(child) <- gsub("*_$", "", names(child))              # REMOVE LAST UNDERSCORE
  names(grandchild) <- gsub(".*_$", "", names(grandchild))   # REMOVE LAST UNDERSCORE
  names(grandchild)[1] <- "mgr_id"

  rbind(child, grandchild)
})

dfList$C

#   mgr_id emp_id
# 1      C      D
# 2      C      E
# 3      C      F
# 4      D     D1
# 5      D     D2
# 6      E     E1
```